# "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" - Button Trigger?

Tags: javascript, html

So I've been trying to get a button within my form to call a function when it's pressed...problem is it reports an error to me saying "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function".

Below is the code that I'm using...

```
<script>
    function lookup() {
        document.getElementByID("isbn").value = "FooBar";
    }
</script>

<form>
    <label for="isbn">ISBN</label>
    <input id="isbn" type="text" name="isbn" placeholder="Enter the ISBN...">
    <button type="Button" id="findButton" onclick="lookup()" >Find</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `console.log();` to see if your `ISBN_lookup()` function is even being called? Also, are you trying to set the value of your text `input` tag using the JS function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be `getElementById` instead of `getElementByID` So

Just change:

```
document.getElementByID("isbn").value = "TESTING A FUNCTION!";
```

to

```
document.getElementById("isbn").value = "TESTING A FUNCTION!";
---------------------^^-------------
```

As javascript is case sensitive especially functions:

See [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById)

Comment: Unbelievable... (in a good way) - Could you explain why the error implies there is no declared function?

Comment: @Kolors because it will check for `getElementByID()` function and there is no existence for it in javascript, so it will throw an exception of `undefined is not a function` which means `getElementByID()` is not defined and `.getElementById()` is there already!